# Moodle as LTI Tool Producer and endless redirection

Tags: java, moodle, lti

I am getting endless redirection while integrating my java application with Moodle using LTI. I have configured moodle to be tool producer and a java servlet as a tool consumer. It works fine with some other tool producers what I found on Internet, however I get endless redirection in chrome with moodle. What could be possible causes?

Thanks

Comment: did you solve it? any code?